# Clarifying definition of $\mathbb{R}\mathbb{P}^n$

Tags: definition, projective-geometry, projective-space

This might be a very silly question, but we know that $\mathbb{R}\mathbb{P}^n$ is defined as the equivalence classes $[x]$ ($x\in\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ nonzero) such that $x \sim y \iff x = \lambda y$ for any real, nonzero $\lambda$.

So, these elements in $\mathbb{R}\mathbb{P}^n$ are lines passing through the origin but without the origin in the line.

My question/problem comes with Lee's definition of $\mathbb{R}\mathbb{P}^n$ as the collection of $1$-dimensional linear subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$. But through this definition, it would make sense that the origin would be included in every equivalence class of $\mathbb{R}\mathbb{P}^n$ since $\textbf{0} \in \text{span}(x)$ for any $x\in\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$.

Why do these two definitions not seem equivalent? What am I missing?

Comment: The "origin" is not a one-dimensional linear subspace of $\Bbb R^{n+1}$.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Yes, I understand that we don't take the origin to it's span since it's span is zero dimensional. But, I guess where the main confusion comes from, is that the span of any set with one vector will include the zero vector (origin).
Edit: I'm an idiot. Never mind, thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are right that these two definitions are not *the same*. But there is a canonical bijection between the two; simply add the origin to each equivalence class to get Lee's definition. In fact this is an *isomorphism* between the two different constructions of real projective space.

Just as there are many different constructions of $\Bbb{R}$, there are many different constructions of $\Bbb{RP}^n$. But the underlying construction is not relevant (most of the time). What matters is that they are *isomorphic* as projective spaces.